# Cannot fill the survey again as different user from community page

Tags: survey, salesforce-survey

I have added survey to my community page. It worked fine when I logged in to community page and filled the survey.
Now I try to fill the survey page as a different login but cannot fill.
I get the error saying that I do not have access to create survey or the get invitation link isn't there.

Comment: The error is "Either you don't have access to respond to this survey or the default survey invitation hasn't been generated."

Comment: Have you checked the obvious areas like different permissions for the different logins?  Please [edit] your post to add more detail about your troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using flow to show the survey link on the community page as a button.
After updating the new survey link for "Outside org Participant" in the flow, I am able to fill the survey as multiple different users.